# Which is more accurate to use as a modal verb: 'can' or 'could'?

Tags: difference, modal-verbs

I need your help. Which one of these two sentences is more accurate?

> 1. Extreme rain **can** cause the river to flood the city

or

> 1. Extreme rain **could** cause the river to flood the city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically correct but they have different senses.

"Extreme rain could cause the river to flood the city".

In the sentence the auxiliary verb "could" conveys two senses as follows:

- Could is the past of can. The sentence means that it was possible or likely that extreme rain might cause the river to flood the city.
- Could is also used to express possibility in the present and future. Here it means it's possible that extreme rain may cause the river to flood the city.

"Extreme rain can cause the the river to flood the city".

We can use "can" to express a general fact i.e. something that usually, but not always, happens. Extreme rain usually, not always, causes the river to flood the city.

Comment: I would say that the sense of "could" being past tense, while morphologically true, is very weak.  If the speaker wanted to clearly talk about this as something in the past, they would say "could have".  The sense of potential/possibility is the strongest.

Comment: http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/could

Comment: @A.Ellet, I appreciate your comments. Agreed.

Answer (score 3):

> Extreme rain could cause the river to flood the city

This sentence expresses the flood risk from an extreme rain as a (real) possibility.

> Extreme rain can cause the river to flood the city

This sentence expresses the flood risk from an extreme rain as a known fact.